# $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}(49-t^2)e^{t^3}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If $\displaystyle f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}(49-t^2)e^{t^3}dt$, on what interval is $f$ increasing?

How does one graph from the interval between a constant and an unknown variable? I don't understand. The rest, I assume you take the anti derivative as usual?

Comment: When is $$f'(x) > 0$$ and use standard differentiation of the integral.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus which gives you immediately $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate the other answers a bit: You don't have to actually perform the integration because:

Consider the antiderivative
$$G(t) = \int g(t) dt = \int (49-t^2)e^{t^3} dt$$
where of course
$$G'(t) = g(t) = (49-t^2)e^{t^3} \ .$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$f(x) = G(x)-G(0) \ .$$

Now a differentiable $f(x)$ is strictly  increasing at $x$ when $f'(x) > 0$. You have
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(G(x)-G(0)) = G'(x) = g(x)$$

so $f$ is increasing when
$$g(x) > 0$$
or in specific when 
$$(49-x^2)e^{x^3} > 0$$
which is equal to 
$$x^2 < 49$$
or 
$$-7<x<7 \ .$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f'(x) = (49-x^2)e^{x^3} > 0 \iff f \text{ is increasing}$.

Comment: Your edit to the $t$s came just in time, I was already typing my complaint :D Sweet solution.